# python filename.py in command line does not work

Tags: python, command-line

temp.py is a simply python scipt prints "hello". This is a simple example. None of my other scripts are running.

For example, something like  `python code.py arg1 arg2`  does not work.

What are the possible reasons and solutions?

[image]

EDIT: After following advice from comments, I think it works now.

[image]

Comment: type "python" in cmd and enter. If you don't enter into the python command line then you don't set the environment variables and your system does not see the python path.

Comment: I entered "python" in command prompt, pressed enter. Then, automatically Microsoft Store opened prompting me to download Python 3.7. I downloaded it. Then it worked. Sorry I am feeling a little silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

type "python" in cmd and enter. If you don't enter into the python command line then you don't set the environment variables and your system does not see the python path.

Answer (score 0):

like the comment suggested, check the ENV_VARIABLES, see where your python module is installed and what version you have. If all those things look good,

then, check your code, a lot of times you maybe missing the

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3
```

at the top of the file, because the cmd line interpreter may not know if this is a python script. So include that shebang executable at top, if that doesn't work either. Pls upload your code on here for others to review...